# PS How to change one shape and effect all of them?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes

I have  a personal project in Photoshop, just wonder if I can change a shape (eg. hands of a human or a body or a head) and effect all the shape which have hands but they are in a different layers. Is taking to much time to edit each shapes.Lets say i have 10 layers with a face and i change my mind that i wanna put a smiles on each face, can I change one layer and effect all of the other 9 layers at the same time?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this can only be done if you convert the face into a smart object and duplicate it.

To try this out do the following:

1. Create a new document
2. Add a new layer and draw a black line in it
3. Right click on that layer and convert it to a Smart Object
4. Right click on the resulting Smart Object and Click duplicate and reposition the duplicated layer in order to see them both.
5. Double click on the original smart object, it will open a new window and you can edit it, add another line there then close the window and save.

The new line should also be present in the second smart object that you duplicated at step 4.

**DEMO:**

[image]

Comment: Really impressive that you showed me, first thanks a lot for answering and wasting your time,second  tested with shapes and is working, yeah, Alin your`re really smart! Thanks again.

Comment: @RusFAdrian well, glad you got it working. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please click on the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as correct. Best of luck!